# Error bound for a Taylor Polynomial

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am trying to understand error bounds for Taylor polynomials.

I have some function:

$$
f(x) = x\sin(3x)
\\ a = 0
\\ n = 4
\\ -0.7 \le x \le 0.7
$$

I was able to approximate my polynomial to $T_4(x) = 3x^2-\frac{9x^4}{2}$

Now I must find $|R_4(x)| \le$ some error value.

I know the formula for taylor series is just $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f^n(a)}{n!}(x-a) $$
and I know I will have to take the fifth derivative of $f(x)$ which is $81(3xcos(3x)+5sin(3x))$. I also know I am only concerned with the bounds $[-0.7, 0.7]$. Please show me how to do a problem like this.

Comment: To find the error of an $n$th degree polynomial, you need at least the $n+1$th derivative.

Comment: So I take the 5th derivative, what now?

Comment: You bound the 5th derivative as I've done in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $T_5(x)=T_4(x)$, and so $R_5(x)=R_4(x)$.  The $6$th derivative of $x\sin(3x)$ may then be calculated using product rule a few times.

$$f^{(6)}(x)=1458\cos(3x)-729x\sin(3x)$$

Since $|\cos(x)|$ and $|\sin(x)|$ are less than or equal to $1$, we find that

$$|f^{(6)}(x)|\le2187$$

And thus,

$$\left|x\sin(3x)-3x^2-\frac92x^4\right|\le\frac{2187}{6!}x^6=\frac{243}{80}x^6$$

Comment: I have no idea what x should be.

Comment: @Computer $x$ is the maximum value on the domain you are looking at.  Here, you have $x\in[-0.7,0.7]$, so $x=0.7$ should be good.

Comment: I get the same answers for 0.7 and -0.7. I am guessing they are symmetric. Either way this answer .3574 is wrong.

Comment: @Computer What is the "correct" answer?  It may be the case that in using $R_6(x)$, I get an tighter bound for the error than the problem wanted from you.

Comment: maybe I should use $R_6(x)$? You did suggest I should use $n+1$

Comment: @Computer I used $R_6$, but the problem probably expects you to use $R_5$.  See Salahaman_Fatima's answer.

Comment: Where'd you get 2187?

Comment: @Computer $|1458\cos(3x)-729\sin(3x)|\le1458+729=2187$

Comment: Did you let x be -.7?

Comment: @Computer Uh, no.  I simply used $|a-b|\le|a|+|b|$ and $|\cos(\theta)|\le1,|\sin(\theta)|\le1$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$f $ is an even function, so $f^{(5)}(0)=0$ and $T_4 (x)=T_5 (x) $.

The error is
$$R_6 (x)=\frac {x^6}{6!}f^{(6)}(c) $$
compute $f^{(6)}(x) $ and use
$$|\sin (3c)|\le 1$$
$$|\cos (3c)|\le 1$$
 $$ |c|\le |x|\le 0,7.$$

You can finish.

Answer (score 0):

$x \sin (3 x)=3 x^2-\dfrac{9 x^4}{2}+\dfrac{81 x^6}{40} +O(x^7)$

Is an alternating series, thus the error $R$ you make truncating at the $x^4$ term is, in absolute value,  less than the first term not considered

$|R|\leq \dfrac{81 |x|^6}{40}\leq \dfrac{81 \cdot 0.7^6}{40}\approx 0.23824$

Actually it is verified by direct calculation

$x \sin (3 x)-\left(3 x^2-\dfrac{9 x^4}{2}\right)\approx 0.2147$ for $x=0.7$